Deserializing JSON string with dynamic keys
I have a JSON string with some key is dynamic.
{
"status": {
    "code": "200",
    "message": "OK"
},
"total": 1,
"results": [
    {
        "leader": "00689cam a2200217 a 4500",
        "fields": [
            {
                "020": {
                    "ind2": "#",
                    "ind1": "#",
                    "subfields": [
                        {
                            "a": "9786041092587"
                        },
                        {
                            "c": "200000đ"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "041": {
                    "ind2": "#",
                    "ind1": "0",
                    "subfields": [
                        {
                            "a": "vie"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
]}

In there, "020", "041", "a", "c" are dynamic keys.
I am trying to deserialize it into a C# object model:
[DataContract]
public class Data
{
    [DataMember]
    public Status status { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int total { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public List<Result> Results { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class Status
{
    [DataMember]
    public string code { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string message { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class Result
{
    [DataMember]
    public string leader { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public List<Field> fields { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class Field
{
    [DataMember]
    List<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class Tag
{
    [DataMember]
    public string ind1 { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string ind2 { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public List<subField> subfields { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class subField
{
    [DataMember]
    public List<sCode> Codes { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class sCode
{
    [DataMember]
    public string key { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string value { get; set; }
}

I am deserializing the JSON format with the code below:
string strJson = f["dataJson"].ToString();
var deserializedData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Data>>(strJson);

I am sure that I'm wrong something here but I can't find them. Any help would be really appreciated! Thanks so much!

Please post code blocks in your question rather than links to images. This makes it easier for others to run and debug your code.

Just to clarify, does f["dataJson"].ToString() return the entire JSON string that you posted above, or just the 'results' portion? What error do you get when running it?

because  "020", "041", "a", "c" are dynamic keys, we can't define them like public List<Field> fields { get; set; } as they doesn't have their own key name, but the deserialization requires us to give a specific key name as the model property. Just like, if we change the codes to public List<Field> fields2222 { get; set; }, we will found property fields2222 be null. Since then, we need to define the dynamic part as List<Dictionary<string, Tag>>

Pls try my codes below.
public void hello() {
     var jsonStr = $@"{{
""total"": 1,
""results"": [
    {{
        ""leader"": ""00689cam a2200217 a 4500"",
        ""fields"": [
            {{
                ""020"": {{
                    ""ind2"": ""#"",
                    ""ind1"": ""#"",
                    ""subfields"": [
                        {{
                            ""a"": ""9786041092587""
                        }},
                        {{
                            ""c"": ""200000đ""
                        }}
                    ]
                }}
            }},
            {{
                ""041"": {{
                    ""ind2"": ""#"",
                    ""ind1"": ""0"",
                    ""subfields"": [
                        {{
                            ""a"": ""vie""
                        }}
                    ]
                }}
            }}
        ]
    }}
]}}";
    Data res = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Data>(jsonStr);
}
        
        
public class Data {
    public int total { get; set; }
    public List<Result> Results { get; set; }

}

public class Result
{
    public string leader { get; set; }
    public List<Dictionary<string, Tag>> fields { get; set; }
}

public class Tag
{
    public string ind1 { get; set; }
    public string ind2 { get; set; }
    public List<Dictionary<string, string>> subfields { get; set; }
}

And here's my test result.


You're trying to deserialise into a dictionary. Changing the type to deserialise into to your Data type seems to work fine.
var deserializedData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Data>(strJson);

https://dotnetfiddle.net/iq8qMa
I'm assuming that f["dataJson"].ToString() returns the JSON string that you posted above.

I have been try but it don't understand '020' is Tag property. So, fields.count =2 but element is null

@Krystal Okay, so the issue is that your Tags are deserialising as null? Can you change the format of the JSON, or is that set in stone?
